# Stacked Highcharts area graph with irregular time intervals displayed incorrectly

Tags: highcharts, flot

I have several series of sampled data with irregular sample times which I want to stack on top of each other.

I cannot seem to get Highcharts to display them as I would expect.

Please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markalroberts/mnj8tkqj/2/) for an example, based on the highcharts demo

I have tried toggling the `connectNulls` setting but this doesn't help me.

I think that Flot gets it right - see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/markalroberts/9x7aJ/5512/) fiddle

Comment: What is incorrect in your graph? How you would like it to look? your points will be stacked only if you have them on the same x value. I think that if you have points on different x values they will not be stacked.

Comment: Multiple series will regular value works fine. Multiple series with only one areaspline works fine. Multiple series will irregular value seems not working as expected.

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński I have added a Flot example with the same data.

Comment: @RockieYang yes. It works fine when the series share the same times - unfortunately, in my data, I am sampling things at slightly different times - but I would expect the stacked chart to still manage to cope with this

Comment: If Flot shows it the way that you want, then you don't want a stacked chart - just remove the stacking:  http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/mnj8tkqj/3/

Comment: If you do, in fact, want stacking despite the flot example, I would say that your best bet is to pre-process your data, and make sure that each series has a point anywhere that any of the series have a point. There isn't really any good way, currently, for the chart to know how to stack points that are not aligned.

Comment: lastly, there is a long standing feature request here that you can add your votes and comments to:  https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/2414260-stacked-area-spline-etc-in-irregular-datetime-se

Comment: @jlbriggs the flot example *is* stacked. Please take another look

Comment: The flot example has been updated so that it is now stacked :)  So, then, take a look at my second and third comments.

Comment: @jlbriggs - yes am actually doing as you say (pre-processing), but it's proving to be a bit of a pain in some cases - when I found the Flot example, it made me realise that this is what I want from Highcharts really :).... shame since Highcharts is really very good in all other ways!